# How to kill a mapred job started by hive?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I'm working by CDH 5.1 now. It starts normal Hadoop job by `YARN` but hive still works with `mapred`. Sometimes a big query will hang for a long time and I want to kill it.

I can find this big job by JobTracker web console while it didn't provide a button to kill it.

Another way is killing by command line. However, I couldn't find any job running by command line.

I have tried 2 commands:

- `yarn application -list`
- `mapred job -list`

How to kill big query like this?

Answer (score 18):

You can get the Job ID from Hive CLI when you run a job or from the Web UI. You can also list the job IDs using the application ID from resource manager. Ideally, you should get everything from

```
mapred job -list
```

or

```
hadoop job -list
```

Using the Job ID you can kill it by using the below command.

```
hadoop job -kill <job_id>
```

Another alternative would be to kill the application using

```
yarn application -kill <application_id>
```

Comment: I tried but failed with `Application with id 'application_201502060008_2375' doesn't exist in RM`, it seems to use `YARN` but `mapred`.

Comment: Substitute "job" for "application"... that should work... the ApplicationId is different from the JobId... the ApplicationId is for Yarn.

Comment: My original command is `hadoop job -kill job_201502060008_2375` and the `job` was replaced with `application`. I don't know why.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can also get the kill command from Hive CLI. It would give you a kill command once the execution kicks off

Comment: Thanks. How could I find the kill command when I closed Hive CLI?

Comment: @2shou can you accept the answer, if it helped you?